# Get Children of New Scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a `GameManager` script which manages loading scenes, putting characters in the scene, reading map information from game objects, and so on.  The `GameManager` script is set to `DontDestroyOnLoad`.

I'm trying to figure out how to access objects within my new scene from `GameManager` after a new scene loads.  I'm using the `SceneManager.sceneLoaded` event to run my "scene initialization" code.  Here's the event handler:

```
 void OnLevelFinishedLoading(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
 { 
    // I want to access GameObjects within the newly loaded scene here
    //
    // SceneManager.GetActiveScene().GetRootGameObjects() returns               
    // System.ArgumentException: the scene is not loaded

    // I want to do something like this
    foreach (MapFeature mapFeature in rootObject.GetComponentsInChildren<MapFeature>())
    {
       // Do something
    }
 }
```

I'm want to get the root level `GameObject` of the new scene, and then use `GetComponentInChildren` on that root object in order to dynamically grab various components in the scene and store them in `GameManager`.  However, `SceneManager.GetActiveScene().GetRootGameObjects()` returns `System.ArgumentException: the scene is not loaded`

How do I get objects from my newly loaded scene within my `GameManager`?  If there's a better method than getting the new scene's root object and using that to get its children, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be possible by a workaround, where the sceneLoaded Event starts a coroutine waiting for the next frame. Relevant snippet below.

For reference, I read this thread on unityforums, recently: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/scenemanager-sceneloaded-event-when-fired-checking-scene-isloaded-false.429659/

```
void Awake () {
    instance = this;
    DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoadedWrapper;
}
void OnSceneLoadedWrapper(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode) {
    StartCoroutine ("OnSceneLoaded");
}

IEnumerator OnSceneLoaded(){
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();
    Scene scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene ();
    int count = scene.GetRootGameObjects ().Length;
    string name = scene.GetRootGameObjects ()[0].name;
    Debug.LogFormat ("{0} root objects in Scene, first one called {1}", count, name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like maybe the events are getting fired in the wrong order, so that `sceneLoaded` is fired before the new scene's initial events?